# How to add a tooltip to a table column header in SWT/JFace

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I am trying to add a tooltip to the column headers of my table. I just can't seem to find any workaround for this.

Do you  have any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `TableColumn` just call the `setToolTipText("text")` method.

If you are using `TableViewerColumn` call `getColumn().setToolTipText("text")`

Comment: how did not see this? I already tried to implement it myself with a MouseHover Event. Oh god